# Best upper bound for $ r_{0}(n) $ under Goldbach and Chowla's conjectures

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, goldbachs-conjecture

Assume Goldbach's conjecture. Then for any large enough composite integer  $ n $   $ r_{0}(n) : =\inf\{r\ge 0,(n-r,n+r)\in\mathbb{P}^{2}\} $ exists and is obviously smaller than  $ n $ . Does the assumption of Chowla's conjecture imply that for all $k>0$ one has $\sup_{n\le x}\{r_{0}(n)\}=O(x^{1/k})$?

Comment: Why [Chowla's conjecture](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/10/14/the-chowla-conjecture-and-the-sarnak-conjecture/) would be of any help to estimate the distribution of Goldbach's numbers $r_0(n)$ ? I'd say the papers on the weak Goldbach conjecture and [Vinogradov's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinogradov%27s_theorem) explain under what assumptions we can estimate $r_0(n),\max_{n \le x} r_0(n), \sum_{n \le x} r_0(n)$.